# Calling scipy special functions on Tensorflow tensors?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, tensorflow2.0

Is there any performance cost when calling scipy/numpy special functions with Tensorflow tensors as arguments? As opposed to using the functions provided by `tensorflow.math`?

I am asking because some special functions are available on scipy but not on Tensorflow (e.g. `scipy.special.erfcx`). I presume that Tensorflow provides the functions within `tensorflow.math` instead of recommending to use numpy or scipy directly because this provides some speedup?

**Edit:** Note that I tried to use `@tf.function`:

```py
import scipy.special
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def erfcx(x):
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(scipy.special.erfcx(x))
```

but I get an error when I call this on a `tf.Tensor`.

```
A = tf.random.uniform((5,6))
erfcx(A)
# NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (x:0) to a numpy array.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: TF has it's own highly optimized CUDA kernels for its operations. So when ever you use a custom function, you run into losing that efficiency (not alwasy as @tf.function can do some bit of converting python to `tf.Graph`). Therefore yes, it is always preferred to use `tf.ops` than other ops. However, the type of speedup you get is different depending on how parallelizable that op in fact is.

Comment: @thushv89 Please see edit. I tried to use `@tf.function` but it gives an error.

Comment: Proabably TF has limitations of what it can convert to TF ops. I was trying to use `tf.numpy_function` but that failed too. I'll have a look and post an answer when I get something up and running

Comment: The scioy functions can't use tensorflow objects directly.  They will try to convert them to numpy arrays first.  Better let tensorfow do the right conversion first.

Answer (score 1):

So you can do the following. However I don't think you can use this function along with `@tf.function` which is probably too difficult for TF to build a graph with. This will be running in Eager execution mode.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.ones(shape=[10,2], dtype=np.float32)
erfcx = tf.numpy_function(scipy.special.erfcx,[x], tf.float32)
```

Comment: Yup it is slower than calling the function it self in fact (unfortunately)

Comment: What about just using `tf.convert_to_tensor(scipy.special.erfcx(x))`? (I'm not sure how you benchmark these things).

Comment: You can use `%timeit` magic command on Jupyter to time these. You could do what you have just mentioned too.